# Count distinct Alias in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am practicing my SQL coding and wanted to expand more on a practice example. I am trying to get a distinct count after using CONCAT to generate an alias. I keep running into errors and can't seem to find a correct way of doing this. Below is my code

```
SELECT 
concat(product_code, product_color) as new_product_code
count (distinct new_product_code)
 FROM `hands-on-project-automobile.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
 where 
 product = 'couch'
 order by new_product_code desc
```

##update##
I am getting a little closer to what I am wanting to achieve thanks to all the feedback. In my new code I attempted my first subquery. It worked, but I still am missing second column giving me a count of the number of new_product_code. e.g. grey couches 2, white couches 3,

```
SELECT 
   distinct new_product_code
   
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         concat(product_code, product_color) as new_product_code
        FROM `hands-on-project-automobile.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
        where 
        product = 'couch'
        order by new_product_code desc
    )
```

screenshot of what I am attempting[image]

##update 2##
Shout out to @shawnt00 for help and everyone else. the final code:

```
SELECT 
   distinct new_product_code,
   count(*) 
   
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         concat(product_code, product_color) as new_product_code
        FROM `hands-on-project-automobile.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
        where 
        product = 'couch'
        order by new_product_code desc
    )
    group by new_product_code
```

and the output
[image]

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: MySql lets you refer to aliased columns this way. But you're also mixing aggregates with non-aggregated data. That's probably the mistake. If you replace the alias name with the original expression it should still generate that same error.

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00 for the feedback. It's my second day really exploring SQL code. This is data based on an example from a course that I am just trying to expand on a little and try different queries on.

Comment: `select newproductcode, count(*) from (subquery) group by newproductcode`

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks @shawnt00

Comment: btw, did you see my recent answer?! w/o subquery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue here is in `count (distinct new_product_code)`
At the time of execution `new_product_code` alias is not available yet for counting
So you need to use below

```
SELECT 
concat(product_code, product_color) as new_product_code,
count (distinct concat(product_code, product_color))
 FROM `hands-on-project-automobile.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
 where 
 product = 'couch'
 order by new_product_code desc
```

> I still am missing second column giving me a count of the number of new_product_code. e.g. grey couches 2, white couches 3,

```
SELECT 
  concat(product_code, product_color) as new_product_code,
  count (1) cnt
FROM `hands-on-project-automobile.customer_data.customer_purchase` 
where product = 'couch'
group by 1
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see where the logic behind the execution. I copied your code and pasted in to BigQuery and am still getting "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "count" at [3:5]"

Comment: thank you for this. It worked as well and was much cleaner and easier to use vs. my subquery workaround.